# MS Access and SSMS return different # of records from exact same query

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, ssms

please help me before I go insane.  I am using SSMS 2008 R2 and MS Access 2010.

I am taking queries from an Access database someone built and putting them into SSMS to eventually become stored procedures.  In most cases this is just a matter of fixing the syntaxical idiosyncracies of Access and it's done.  But a few are always giving me different results and I cannot nail down why.  Here is one such query.  This is the SSMS version.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
 a.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
,a.INVESTOR_CODE
,a.APPLICATION_PROCESS_STATUS
,i.DOCUMENT_INTAKE_START_DATE
,a.APPLICATION_TYPE_DESC
,p.DECISION_STATUS_DESC
,p.DECISION_STATUS_DATE
,p.DECISION_PROCESS_STATUS
,a.INVESTOR_NAME
FROM        V_Application_Process a
LEFT JOIN   V_Document_Intake_Process i ON a.APPLICATION_ID = i.APPLICATION_ID
LEFT JOIN   V_Decision_Process p ON a.APPLICATION_ID = p.APPLICATION_ID
```

When I run this in SSMS, I get **107614** results.  When I run it in Access, I get **90848**.  I will paste the Access version of the query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
 dbo_V_Application_Process.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
,dbo_V_Application_Process.INVESTOR_CODE
,dbo_V_Application_Process.APPLICATION_PROCESS_STATUS
,dbo_V_Document_Intake_Process.DOCUMENT_INTAKE_START_DATE
,dbo_V_Application_Process.APPLICATION_TYPE_DESC
,dbo_V_Decision_Process.DECISION_STATUS_DESC
,dbo_V_Decision_Process.DECISION_STATUS_DATE
,dbo_V_Decision_Process.DECISION_PROCESS_STATUS
,dbo_V_Application_Process.INVESTOR_NAME

FROM
((dbo_V_Application_Process
LEFT JOIN dbo_V_Document_Intake_Process
ON dbo_V_Application_Process.APPLICATION_ID = dbo_V_Document_Intake_Process.APPLICATION_ID)
LEFT JOIN dbo_V_Decision_Process
ON dbo_V_Application_Process.APPLICATION_ID = dbo_V_Decision_Process.APPLICATION_ID)
```

I have compared each view by doing `SELECT * FROM V_Application_Process etc.` and compared it to the passthroughs that the Access query is based off of (which are passthrough connections to those very same views) and they always return the exact same results.  So, the views the query is based on are identical, but put them together in the same way and get different results.

Does anyone know why?

**EDIT**

Okay, so I noticed that one field that is not supposed to be NULL is NULL when all three of these views are joined in Access (SSMS is fine).  So in Access I made a test query with the APplication Process and Document Intake Process views joined on application ID.  I used one test account.  It works fine.  Then I did another with the Application process and Decision process views joined on application ID.  it works fine.  Finally, I joined all three tables on application ID.  on this test account, when I do that, I get zero results.  So the joins on the views work great until you enter three into the mix, and I have no idea why.

Comment: Is `dbo_V_Application_Process` a table in MS Access linked back to `V_Application_Process` in SQL Server? I suggest you order your datasets and compare them, find the first missing record and dig in and find out why that record is missing.

Comment: I haven't had much experience with Access and I'm fairly new with SSMS, so I might be way off here, but I would try removing the parentheses in the FROM section of the access query, or adding them to the ssms query.

Comment: I just tested this out on several of my own tables, and it didn't cause any discrepancies, so maybe not, though I could swear I've seen the same thing happen to me before and that was the solution...

Comment: Have you solved this yet?

Comment: I just got into work, i need to try this stuff

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid yes.  I did what you said and it helped, please see my edit to my question

Comment: You didn;t try teh other combination of views...  Decision process views and  Document Intake Process views   (or did you!)   (PS.  Can't you just create  a view in SQL Server that has the above SQL then link it as a table from access - as per my answer?)

Comment: @HarveyFrench I will try the other combo of views now, unfortunately I don't have permission to create views at my job, i can only use the ones that exist or request new ones

Comment: For performance reasons (alone) you should request one!

Comment: @HarveyFrench wow, the other combo (decision and intake) works as well.  Any two will work together, three throws this error.

Comment: Is it just the one field that is NULL or is the whole row null?  What are teh three values in the fields that result in a null?  It's beating me.What about puting all 3 views in the SQL but changing the order and the "order" the views are joined?  Will it still give NULl I wonder?

Comment: @HarveyFrench I will play around with that but for this test, I'm only including the application ID column of each view, to see if they match.  In the all three views scenario, they are all blank, but in all other scenarios, it gives me the right ID and two records, which is right

Comment: Ah.  So it must be how they are joined together!  Are they the same two records returned by each view.  Is the ID field numeric (could space be hidden from you - crazy I know!)

Comment: @HarveyFrench yes they are the same.  The ID field in an integer in all SSMS views but text in all Access linked tables that make up the Access query, i think due to the nature of linked tables, or whoever built it didn't know to change it to be integer.

Comment: For what it is worth, doing all three with the two views as INNER JOINs returns NULL results, but LEFT JOINs returns a Datatype Mismatch error.  Even though they are the same data type.  I am trying every combination of JOIN and order of views I can and nothing is working.  Since the project is to get these queries OUT of access and into SSMS, I'm thinking I should maybe trust that SSMS is right and Access is messing up, and continue with my project.  It'd be nice to figure this out but as long as Access it the problem, it's sort of okay since we're trying to abandon it.

Comment: Delete the access linked tables then free add them.  It has to be how they are set up. There is no way your id column should be varchar IF SS is Integer

Comment: I refer you to PART 2 of my answer!  (Please upvote and flag as an answer if you deem appropriate!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding to what Andre said, how about replacing all the columns in the SELECT clause with all the Primary key ID fields used in the joins.  Will this still give different results?

If so identify the rows that are missing and see if they have anything in common.

I've just noticed all your tables have dbo_ at the start.  For pass through queries I was expecting dbo.  (See [this webpage for more info](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1482/microsoft-access-pass-through-queries-to-sql-server/) )

This tells me your SQL Server query is NOT running on the SQL server, but I think it is using the tables you have linked to SQL Server from access that all begin with dbo_

This will bring into play other possible issues (ie the ODBC driver and which columns have been set up as the primary key for the linked tables - I think).

PART2:

Note that instead of writing an access query like your one below, you would be better to create the query below as a view on SQL Server and then "link to" the view in access.  This way SQL Server will do more of the processing and less data is transferred to access.

Here's a reformatted version of your Access query (with aliases)

```
SELECT DISTINCT vAP.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
              , vAP.INVESTOR_CODE
              , vAP.APPLICATION_PROCESS_STATUS
              , vDIP.DOCUMENT_INTAKE_START_DATE
              , vAP.APPLICATION_TYPE_DESC
              , vDP.DECISION_STATUS_DESC
              , vDP.DECISION_STATUS_DATE
              , vDP.DECISION_PROCESS_STATUS
              , vAP.INVESTOR_NAME

SELECT DISTINCT vAP.APPLICATION_ID
              , vDIP.APPLICATION_ID
              , vDP.APPLICATION_ID

           FROM ((dbo_V_Application_Process AS vAP
                      LEFT JOIN dbo_V_Document_Intake_Process AS vDIP
                             ON vAP.APPLICATION_ID = vDIP.APPLICATION_ID
                 )
                 LEFT JOIN dbo_V_Decision_Process AS vDP
                        ON vAP.APPLICATION_ID = vDP.APPLICATION_ID)
```

Comment: The parentheses around the joins are Access syntax, so the second query is indeed a "native" Access query, not pass-through. If a pass-through query in Access would yield different results than the same query in SSMS, things would go from weird to crazy. :)

Comment: @Andre. So, it could be the way has configured the tables in access that link to SQL Server.  I seem to remember that you have to choose which column is your primary key when the table is created.  I wonder if selected the right one. (I added part 2 to my answer)

Comment: @HarveyFrench this is good info and still might be relevant, but take a look at my edit of the question.  I discovered some things that might change my understanding of the problem/solution

Answer (score 0):

If you remove `DISTINCT` from both queries, do you get the same number of results?

If yes, my guess would be that some SQL Server datatypes have no exact equivalent in Access, so maybe some values that are different in SQL Server get mapped to identical values in Access, and therefore their records get identical and thus removed by DISTINCT.

My first suspect would be **Date** fields. Which datatype are you using in SQL Server for them?

Comment: I have removed distinct on both, on the SSMS one it's fine but the Access one times out (ODBC Call Failed).  My data types are BIGINT
INT
VARCHAR(20)
DATETIME
VARCHAR(150)
VARCHAR(20)
DATETIME
VARCHAR(20)

Comment: i will remove both dates and try it

Comment: interesting! the results are the same # if I take out the date fields.  But i don't know if it's because the date data is bad, or if the number just expands when more unique records are available due to different dates